# Insert JSON to salesforce

Tags: apex, json, dml, upsert

I have a JSON which I got from An outer System to Salesforce and I should eventually insert it to SF.

```
{
  "AFTR0": [
    {
      "AFTR1":"U",
      "AFTR2": "3dcda8f9213ad43aafe456ae489a158b",
      "AFTR3": 123456789,
      "AFTR4": "aaa",
      "AFTR5": "bbb",
      "AFTR6": 1,
      "AFTR7": 1944,
      "AFTR8": 71,
      "AFTR9": 1994,
      "AFTR10": 1,
      "AFTR11": 1,
      "AFTR12": 2001,
      "AFTR13": 2005,
      "AFTR14": "Bbb",
      "AFTR15": "Aaa",
      "DFTE0": [
        {
              "DFTE1":"U",
          "DFTE2": 12354678,
          "DFTE3": 2,
          "DFTE4": 1234567,
          "DFTE5": 123,
          "DFTE6": 1234,
          "DFTE7": 123
        }
      ],
      "TRYG0": [
        {
              "TRYG1":"U",
          "TRYG2": 1234,
          "TRYG3": "01",
          "TRYG4": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

"AFTR0" is including 15 fields and 2 more arrays.

"AFTR0", "DFTE0", "TRYG0" are sObjects in Salesforce.

My question is - since DML inside apex is not (definitely not) recommended - How should I need to plan my code to deserialize it?

I need to use the Id of the upserted value - How can it do without a loop?

The bottom line here - is how can I use the Id of a list In the JSON after I upserting it to  SObject in SF - for another list inside the JSON that should be read in the same transaction of a for loop.

What I did is (DML inside loop) :

```
global class InegrationWithChickWS {

    static final String CLASSNAME = InegrationWithChickWS.class.getName();

    public static void AFTR0ToUpdate(String jsonToParse){
        String jsn = jsonToParse;
        RootObject data = (RootObject) JSON.deserialize(jsn, RootObject.class);
        System.debug('data  -> ' + data );
        Map<String,Id> countryMap = getCountryMap(); 
        Map<String,Id> citiesMap = getCitiesMap();

        for(AFTR0__c curAFTR : data.AFTR0){


            fillData(curAFTR,countryMap,citiesMap);






        }
    }

public class DFTE0 {
        public String DFTE1;
        public Integer DFTE2;
        public Integer DFTE3;
        public Integer DFTE4;
        public Integer DFTE5;
        public Integer DFTE6;
        public Integer DFTE7;
    }

    public class TRYG0 {
        public String TRYG1;
        public Integer TRYG2;
        public String TRYG3;
        public Integer TRYG4;
    }



    public class AFTR0 {
        public String AFTR1;
        public String AFTR2;
        public Integer AFTR3;
        public String AFTR4;
        public String AFTR5;
        public Integer AFTR6;
        public Integer AFTR7;
        public Integer AFTR8;
        public Integer AFTR9;
        public Integer AFTR10;
        public Integer AFTR11;
        public Integer AFTR12;
        public Integer AFTR13;
        public String AFTR14;
        public String AFTR15;
        public List<DFTE0> DFTE0;
        public List<TRYG0> TRYG0;
    }


    public class RootObject {
        public List<AFTR0> AFTR0;
    }





    private static void fillData(InegrationWithChickWS.AFTR0 curAFTR,Map<String,Id> countryMap,Map<String,Id> citiesMap){


        Id AFTRId = Insert_Update_AFTR(curAFTR,countryMap,citiesMap); //Upsert the first Object

        insert_Update_Related_To_AFTR0(AFTRId,curAFTR); // Upsert related Objects to AFTR0 

        Id TRYGId =  Insert_Update_TRYG0(AFTRId,curAFTR); //Upsert the first list inside AFTR0

        Id DFTEId =  Insert_Update_DFTE0(AFTRId,curAFTR); //Upsert the Second List inside AFTR0




    }


    private static Map<String,Id> getCountryMap(){
        Map<String,Id> countryMap = new Map<String,Id>();

        List<Country__c> clist = [SELECT Id,country_code__c,SomeCode__c FROM country_list__c];

        for(country_list__c cl : clist){
            countryMap.put(cl.SomeCode__c,cl.Id);
        }

        return countryMap;

    }

    private static Map<String,Id> getCitiesMap(){
        Map<String,Id> citiesMap = new Map<String,Id>();
        List<City__c> citiesList = [SELECT Id,SomeCode__c FROM City__c WHERE Rakefet_Code__c!=null];
        for(City__c curCity : citiesList){
            citiesMap.put(curCity.SomeCode__c,curCity.Id);
        }

        return citiesMap;
    }




    private static Id Insert_Update_AFTR(InegrationWithChickWS.AFTR0 curAFTR, Map<String,Id> countryMap,Map<String,Id> citiesMap){
        AFTR0__c astr = new AFTR0__c();
        astr.Field1 = String.valueOf(curAFTR.AFTR1);
        astr.Field2 = curAFTR.AFTR2;
        astr.Field3 = curAFTR.AFTR3
        astr.Field4 = curAFTR.AFTR4;
        astr.Field5= curAFTR.AFTR5;
        astr.Field6=String.valueOf(curAFTR.AFTR6);
        astr.Field7=curAFTR.AFTR7;

//How can I change those lines of code to be out of the loop?
        try{
            Database.upsert(astr, AFTR0__c.Fields.astr_customId__c);
            return astr.Id;
        }catch(Exception e){
            ErrorHandler geh = new ErrorHandler(e,CLASSNAME);
        }


        return null;
    } 

}
```

Comment: the code is not clear in some places. This variable 'curStudt' you have not mentioned anywhere but used in 'Insert_Update_AFTR' method. Can you check and update your code?

Comment: Just did. Sorry about it @Arabinda

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing the operation inside a for loop, you can break the operation into multiple steps.I just framed a sample to break your logic into multiple part. Chck this -

```
map < Integer, AFTR0__c > allAFTR0Map = new map < Integer, AFTR0__c > ();

Integer index = 0;
for (AFTR0__c curAFTR : data.AFTR0)
{
    AFTR0__c astr = new AFTR0__c();
    astr.Field1 = String.valueOf(curAFTR.AFTR1);
    astr.Field2 = curAFTR.AFTR2;
    astr.Field3 = curAFTR.AFTR3
    astr.Field4 = curAFTR.AFTR4;
    astr.Field5= curAFTR.AFTR5;
    astr.Field6=String.valueOf(curAFTR.AFTR6);
    astr.Field7=curAFTR.AFTR7;

    allAFTR0Map.put(index, astr);
    index++;
}

upsert allAFTR0Map.values()  AFTR0__c.Fields.astr_customId__c;

//As the DML opearation done on the map, you can use it to access that particular record by the index and get the ID of that record 

//2nd related list processing
map < Integer, your2ndObj > all2nObjMap = new map < Integer, your2ndObj > ();

Integer index1 = 0;
for (AFTR0__c curAFTR : data.AFTR0)
{
    2ndObj obj = new 2ndObj();

    obj.AFTR0_Id = allAFTR0Map.get(index1).Id;
    //your logic
    all2nObjMap.put(index1, obj);
    index1++;
}

upsert all2nObjMap.values();
```